# How to work with Haskell Array in inline-c

Tags: arrays, haskell, multidimensional-array

There's a `Context` for vectors: `vecCtx` which allows access to Haskell `vector` from C code.

I need to work with multi-dimentional arrays so `vector` doesn't cut for me. I prefer to use `array`. But there isn't a `Context` for it. Do people somehow can still work with arrays or do they create a special context for arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance for a [`StorableArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array/docs/Data-Array-Storable.html#t:StorableArray) like so:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}
module Array where

import Data.Array.Storable
import Foreign.Storable (Storable)
import Language.C.Inline.Context
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

instance (Ix ix, Storable e) => VecCtx (StorableArray ix e) where
  type VecCtxScalar (StorableArray ix e) = e
  vecCtxLength = rangeSize . unsafePerformIO . getBounds
  vecCtxUnsafeWith = withStorableArray
```

Note that it is safe to use `unsafePerformIO` here because `getBounds` is really a pure function underneath for `StorableArray`. There is no immutable storable array in `array` package, so you are sort of stuck in a mutable world with it, which might be fine, considering that your goal is to interface with C.

That being said, I highly recommend checking out library for dealing with multi-dimensional arrays that's called [`massiv`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/massiv). In case you do give it a try, here is how to create `VecCtx` instance for massiv storable mutable and immutable arrays:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}
module Massiv where

import Data.Massiv.Array
import Data.Massiv.Array.Unsafe (unsafeWithPtr)
import Language.C.Inline.Context

instance (Index ix, Storable e) => VecCtx (Array S ix e) where
  type VecCtxScalar (Array S ix e) = e
  vecCtxLength = totalElem . size
  vecCtxUnsafeWith = unsafeWithPtr

instance (Index ix, Storable e) => VecCtx (MArray RealWorld S ix e) where
  type VecCtxScalar (MArray RealWorld S ix e) = e
  vecCtxLength = totalElem . sizeOfMArray
  vecCtxUnsafeWith = withPtr
```